# Space before referencing an equation

Tags: spacing, cross-referencing

when I label an equation in the `equation` environment and refer to it via `\ref{eq1}` and when I write in the text

```
 Eq. \ref{eq1}
```

there is a one more white space between `Eq.` and the reference.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format- in particular, could you explicitly say what your question is?

Comment: I dont want the additional space between Eq and the number of the equation

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely a visual difference due to the `Eq.` being considered an end-of-sentence space. You can avoid this by forcing a regular space (that is, `Eq.\ \ref{eq1}`), or even better, use `Eq.~\ref{eq1}`, or even *more* better, add `\usepackage{amsmath}` to your document preamble and use `Eq.~\eqref{eq1}`.

Here are the options, visually:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
A simple quadratic equation:
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \label{quadratic}
\end{equation}
\indent See Eq. \ref{quadratic}. \par
See Eq.\ \ref{quadratic}. \par
See Eq.~\ref{quadratic}. \par
See Eq.~\eqref{quadratic}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have to hand out may bchelor thesis tomorrow and I have a lot of Eq. and I dont want to change this manually. Can I do this via a renewcommand? :-)

Comment: @lambda1990: That's unfortunate. Do you use any cross-referencing packages that could influence the way `\ref` works? Like [`varioref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varioref), [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref), [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), ...?

Comment: @lambda1990: Why not just do a search-and-replace for `Eq. ` to `Eq.~`?

Comment: Do a global search and replace of `Eq. \ref` -> `Eq.~\ref`.

Comment: @lambda1990: A really ambitious attempt would be to use `\let\oldref\ref \def\ref{\unskip\nobreakspace\oldref}` in your preamble. But then you can't use `\eqref`, and other things may break... undoubtedly.